# Strongly typed MVC View Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to strongly type my MVC View Model that is rendered as a ASP.NET ASPX page.  Everything is in one big project.  However, it say it can't find the name space, what am I doing wrong?

Here is the error:

```
CS0234: The type or namespace name 'MyModel' does not exist in the namespace 
'MyProject.Models' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

Here is my custom Model:

```
namespace MyProject.Models {
    public class MyModel{
        public string companyID { get; set; }
        public MyModel(string companyID){
            this.companyID = companyID;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my Strongly Typed View rendered in ASPX, with the filename MyStronglyTypedView.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MyProject.Models.MyModel>" %>
<%@ import namespace='MyProject.Models' %>
.....
<script runat="server">
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        var curCompany = Model.companyID;
    }
</script>
....
```

And here is how I am calling the page and passing my model to it (I am calling it on a separate Razor page as a partial):

```
@Html.Partial("MyStronglyTypedView",new MyProject.Models.MyModel("1"))
```

Comment: Is `MyProject.Models` defined in an assembly separate from your web application project?  Do you explicitly include a reference to `MyProject.Models` from your web app?

Comment: No, everything is in one project, so I do not believe it need to include itself as a reference.

Comment: btw. why tag 'razor'? you do not use 'razor'... [which is strange IMHO]

Comment: I call the aspx page on a separate razor page, notice the last code block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error you are experiencing occurs because of incorrect `Page` directive `Inherits` attribute value. Directives are part of the ASP.NET markup and thus are not language-specific. For example

```
System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MyProject.Models.MyModel>
```

is how you specify generic type in C#, but say in VB.NET it would be

```
System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage(of MyProject.Models.MyModel)
```

All in all, types here should be specified in CLR notation. In your case it might look something like

```
System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage`1[[MyProject.Models.MyModel, MyProject, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]]
```

This is so called Fully Qualified Type Name. To see this name for a particular type, one can use `Type.FullName` property:

```
Type targetType = typeof(System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<MyProject.Models.MyModel>);
string name = targetType.FullName;
```

Comment: Are you sure your syntax is correct?  What is up with the `1?

Comment: @YongkeBillYu, this is so called fully qualified type name, and `1[[..]] is how generics are specified in this notation.

Comment: I tried it and it does not work, it says it could not load type MyProject.Models.MyModel.

Comment: @YongkeBillYu, are you sure type name you have specified is correct? To obtain the correct fully qualified type name please see update to the post.